# How to authenticate user using Google.GData.Apps of .net?

Tags: c#

I am using google provisioning api on my website. I created a domain on google and some users. Now I want to authenticate them using AppsService class.

```
AppsService service = new AppsService("domain", "admin username", "admin password");
UserEntry user = service.RetrieveUser("username");
```

These two lines I found everywhere. But I want to authenticate user with his username and password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mayank, if you want to authenticate user with his personal username and password, please try [Google Oauth2.0](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2) , not the above code,which is 2-legged oauth 1.0.  The code you posted is for whole domain authentication.  For personal user, please use OAuth2.0, through which a login webpage is poped up when you login, and afterwards you will get the tokens for further operations.

Comment: Mayank, cannot understand why you want to authenticate user with his personal username and password.  For Google Apps domain application, the administrator has right to operate every account.

Comment: You are right. I want to give user a way to change his password through my app. For that purpose first I want to authenticate the user.

Comment: If you want users to operate their personal account, like changing their own password, you need a different authentication method - OAuth2.0.  And I would suggest this app separated from (not integrated into) the domain-wide app.  Based on my knowledge(may not right), 2-legged oauth is not compatible with oauth 2 currently.